# didScrollToTop in UIScrollView

Tags: iphone, ios, uiscrollview

Can anyone tell me how this method is invoked in UIScrollView. Is this done programatically ?

Or Its is done by tapping the status bar(which I am not able to do in the simulator)

Comment: this method is called automatically by the system, but you can simulate and scroll to the top using `scrollRectToVisible:`

Answer (score 0):

You can do this manually by doing...

```
[scrollView scrollRectToVisible:CGRectMake(0,0,10,10)];
```

This will make that rect visible which is the equivalent of scrolling to the top.

The scrollsToTop property is triggered by the status bar tap.

Once it has scrolled the system will then trigger the "didScrollToTop" method which you can then set up for the delegate to receive it.

Comment: I have tried this earlier but the BreakPoint is not getting triggered

Comment: Ah, maybe didScrollToTop isn't triggered. You could just use didScroll. Then check the offset.y == 0. Then do your code.

Comment: Sorry but if I have to check y==0 then what is the meaning of didScrollToTop?

Comment: No idea, only trying to help. I guess didScrollToTop only responds to the actual "ScrollToTop" from the status bar? Just trying to provide alternative solutions.

Comment: Ok so that bar that displays signal and carrier name when we tap that then did scroll is fired  ? I am learning these delegates and just wanted to know what it actually does and thanks for the alternative much appreciated

Comment: The didScroll is trigger by the actual scrollView itself.  The chain goes something like this... User presses button - something happens to the UI - call back method is called to let the developer know that something happened. didScrollToTop is not triggered by the user, it is triggered by the scrollView after scrolling to the top. I imagine (not 100% certain) that didScrollToTop is only triggered after the scrollView responds to the user pressing the status bar.

Answer (score 0):

From documentation for scrollsToTop property of UIScrollView(http://developer.apple.com/library/ios/#documentation/uikit/reference/UIScrollView_Class/Reference/UIScrollView.html)

*This gesture works on a single visible scroll view;

if there are multiple scroll views (for example, a date picker) with this property set, or if the delegate returns `NO` in `scrollViewShouldScrollToTop:`, `UIScrollView` ignores the request.*

Probably you have more than one table or scroll views on screen, hence this is not working for you.

Comment: I have a scroll View and a UITextView(It has scroll), so that is the problem ?

Comment: Yes, that is the problem. Set scrollToTop of textView(or all other scrollviews except one you want to scrolls to top) to 'NO'.
    [textView setScrollsToTop:NO];

Comment: But I havnt made the TextView an outlet still it affects my code ?

Comment: It dosen't matter. If there are multiple scroll views are visible on view then it will not work. There should be only one scroll view with scrollToTop set to 'YES' then only it will work.

Comment: We set outlet for view so that we can access it programatically.